# Ajax.BeginForm + prevent submit on enter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with unobstrusive ajax and I would like to prevent submit form by enter. I wrote the following code to do that

```
$(window).keypress(function (event) { 
    if (event.which == 13) { 
       event.preventDefault(); 
    } 
});
```

Unfortunately this event is not triggered on IE8. Is there any other options. (I'm using jQuery 1.6.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set focus on next element in DOM

```
$(window).keypress(function (event) { 
    if (event.which == 13) { 
       $(this).next().focus(); 
    } 
});
```

Check the next element type, if the type is not a textarea (enters permitted), or button/submit (enter = click) then we just tab to the next thing.

example,

```
if (e.which == 13) {
        var $targ = $(e.target);

        if (!$targ.is("textarea") && !$targ.is(":button,:submit")) {
            var focusNext = false;
            $(this).find(":input:visible:not([disabled],[readonly]), a").each(function(){
                if (this === e.target) {
                    focusNext = true;
                }
                else if (focusNext){
                    $(this).focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The main problem is that this event is not triggered in IE8. In IE9 it works fine.

Comment: try e.keyCode instead of e.which in IE. also you want to use keydown() instead of keypress() in IE. check this out http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: @Priyank - nice add-on comment :P

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:  Oh, just reread your question - in IE you probably want to target `$(window).keydown(function(event)` instead of keypress

I think in IE, you have to look at the event.keyCode property

```
$(window).keypress(function (event) {
if(event && event.which){ //if which property of event object is supported (NN4)
characterCode = event.which //character code is contained in NN4's which property
}
else{
characterCode = event.keyCode //character code is contained in IE's keyCode property
}

if (characterCode == 13){
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/) to make sure that you key press or key down even gets picked up in your browser. If you don't want that event to return anything, then simply `return false;`